# Unbiasedness of estimators of conditional expectation with discrete dependent variable

Tags: least-squares, conditional-expectation, unbiased-estimator

I'm trying to figure out whether the basic formula for a conditional expectation with discrete conditioning variable (let's call it $X$).

The basic argument can go something like the following: a conditional expectation with discrete conditioning variable is a saturated regression, therefore the zero conditional mean condition from OLS holds and therefore we have unbiasedness. The problem here is with the condition that there is variation in $X$, which in the case of a discrete $X$ is violated on a subset which is not of measure 0.

Is there any way around this? In particular, it seems to me that one simply drops the cases with zero variation (and I mean drop, not assign them a value such as 0), then unbiasedness holds again? Is there a way of formalizing this intuition?

---

Let's take the example of $X$ a binary variable (and we assume $0<p<1$). We then have:

$E(Y|X=1) = \frac{E(Y|X=1)}{E(X)}$

An estimator (which also corresponds to the OLS estimator) is:

$\widehat{E(Y|X=1)} = \frac{\overline{YX}}{\overline{X}}$

The problem appears clearly here already since if $X_i = 0 \quad \forall i$, then $\overline{X} = 0$ and the above expression is not defined.

At first sight, unbiasedness is not obvious because it is a quotient of unbiased estimators, but taking a page out of the proof of unbiasedness of OLS:

$\widehat{E(Y|X=1)} = E(Y|X=1) + \frac{\overline{\epsilon X}}{\overline{X}}$

where $\epsilon_i \equiv Y_i - E(Y|X=1)$. Then by taking LIE with respect to the $X_i$ and using iid, you get unbiasedness EXCEPT for the fact that $P(X_i = 0, \forall i) \neq 0$ is non-negible. As far as I can tell, there are two options:

1. One chooses an arbitrary number for the case $X_i = 0 \quad \forall i$. Let's call it $\gamma$ and then, I think, we get:
   $BIAS = (\gamma - E(Y|X=1))P(X_i = 0, \forall i)$
2. One simply takes the average over the set $\{X_i, \forall i\}-\{X_i = 0, \forall i\}$ and then we have "unbiasedness". But is this true? And if so, does that correspond to a notion of unbiasedness? In particular, it seems to depend on data ...

Comment: Although the thrust of your question is clear, it appears to rely on an unstated formula for some kind of expectation.  Could you please include that formula in your post so that we can be sure we know what you're asking?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your answer. I have added a section, hopefully that makes the question clearer.